# Postgres Explain Plans Are Different for same query with different parameter

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I don't know why `explain` query produces different results as I run the following query with different parameter values `sender_id = 2015` vs `sender_id = 2016`:

- With `sender_id = 2015`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    *
FROM
    shipment.shipments shipment0_
WHERE
    (shipment0_.status IN (0 ,1 ,2))
    AND shipment0_.sender_id = 2015
ORDER by shipment0_.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..4.92 rows=10 width=11006)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using shipments__id_pk on shipments shipment0_  (cost=0.43..446315.18 rows=993372 width=11006)
        Filter: ((sender_id = 2015) AND (status = ANY ('{0,1,2}'::bigint[])))
```

- With `sender_id = 2016`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    *
FROM
    shipment.shipments shipment0_
WHERE
    (shipment0_.status IN (0 ,1 ,2))
    AND shipment0_.sender_id = 2016
ORDER by shipment0_.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..16.33 rows=10 width=11006)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_sender_id_id on shipments shipment0_  (cost=0.43..155621.11 rows=97858 width=11006)
        Index Cond: (sender_id = 2016)
        Filter: (status = ANY ('{0,1,2}'::bigint[]))
```

In `shipment.shipments` table has 1M records with `sender_id = 2015`:

```
select count(*) from shipment.shipments where sender_id = 2015; -- 1000000 records
select count(*) from shipment.shipments where sender_id = 2016; -- 90000 records
```

Here are DDL of the table `shipment.shipments`:

```
CREATE TABLE shipment.shipments (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    shp_date varchar(50) NULL,
    shp_time varchar(50) NULL,
    sender_id int8 NULL,
    status int8 NULL,
    pickup_order_id int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT shipments__id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT shipments__pickup_orders_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (pickup_order_id) REFERENCES shipment.pickup_orders(id)
);
CREATE INDEX idx_sender_id_id ON shipment.shipments USING btree (sender_id, id DESC);
CREATE INDEX shipments__sender_id_idx ON shipment.shipments USING btree (sender_id);
```

The query with `sender_id = 2016` runs very fast with `order by limit` but with `sender_id = 2015` it's very slow and not use index `idx_sender_id_id`. Could you help me explain it? and how to improve the speed of the query with `sender_id = 2015`. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL ? Don't spam tag different RDBMS please.

Comment: Indices are used only when the statistics collected for them show that using it has a significant advantage over a full scan with a filter. In this case, 2016 has a significant advantage (a small subset), but 2015 is more than 90% of the bulk. A full scan with a filter is more efficient.

Comment: You could try to create [extended statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html) on those two columns so that the planner recognizes the dependencies.

Comment: Compare the expected row counts. If you need more specific answers, add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question.